# SQLite UPDATE fails to overwrite existing value

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have the following problem that has me stumped.  As a note to keep in mind, I am using a precompiled sqlite3.dll rather than Qt's built-in SQLite support.

Table creation code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE STUDY(
    Name NOT NULL, 
    UserName NOT NULL REFERENCES USERS(UserName), 
    Description DEFAULT NULL, 
    PathToOsirixDB DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(Name, UserName)
)
```

The following C++ code fails to update the value in column `PathToOsirixDB` if it already contains a value.

It fails silently, with no error returned.  That would imply that no rows are matched in the UPDATE.  However, if I take the same UPDATE with valid entries for `user` and `study` to match a row and run it via either the SQLite Manager Firefox plugin, or the command line tool, it works properly.

```
void CStudyDatabase::SetOsirixDBForStudy(const QString user, const QString study, const QString path)
{
    if (mp_db)
    {
        int before = sqlite3_total_changes(mp_db);
        QString insert = QString("UPDATE STUDY SET PathToOsirixDB = '%1' WHERE Name = '%2' AND UserName = '%3'").arg(path, study, user);
        if (!InsertData(insert))
        {
            int after = sqlite3_total_changes(mp_db);

            if (after - before >= 1)
            {
                SetOsirixDB(path.toAscii().data());
                emit ReturnOsirixDB(osirix_db);
            }
            else
            {
                emit DatabaseError(QString("Failed to update the target path."));
            }
       }
   }
}
```

And for Insert Data

```
int CStudyDatabase::InsertData(const QString insert)
{
    char *err_msg = 0;
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(mp_db,
                      insert.toStdString().c_str(),
                      NULL,
                      this,
                      &err_msg);
    if (rc)
        SignalDatabaseError(&err_msg);

    return rc;
}
```

Any insights are appreciated.  Thank you.

UPDATE: added the following code to `SetOsiriXDBForStudy` to see if we actually find a row to update:

```
osirix_db = QString("");

QString query = QString("SELECT PathToOsirixDB FROM STUDY WHERE Name = '%1' AND UserName = '%2'").arg(study, user);
int rc = 0;
char *err_msg = 0;

rc = sqlite3_exec(mp_db,
                      query.toStdString().c_str(),
                      &OsirixDBCallback,
                      this,
                      &err_msg);
if (rc)
    SignalDatabaseError(&err_msg);

if (!(QString(osirix_db).isEmpty()))
    studyrowfound = true;
```

In this case, it leaves osirix_db as an empty string.

But, if I execute this function:

```
void CStudyDatabase::QueryOsirixDB(const QString user, const QString study)
{
    int rc = 0;
    char *err_msg = 0;

    // we query the OrisixDB via the callback and then emit the signal if all went well
    QString query = QString("SELECT PathToOsirixDB FROM STUDY WHERE Name = '%1' AND UserName = '%2'").arg(study, user);

    rc = sqlite3_exec(mp_db,
                  query.toStdString().c_str(),
                  &OsirixDBCallback,
                  this,
                  &err_msg);
    if (rc)
        SignalDatabaseError(&err_msg);

    if (QString(osirix_db).isEmpty())
        emit NeedToSetOsirixDB(user, study, QString());
    else
        emit ReturnOsirixDB(osirix_db);
}
```

Then it does correctly retrieve the expected value into osirix_db.

Last update: found the problem.  It was leading spaces on `user` and `study`.  Had been staring at the same debugger statements for too long and glossed over the extra spaces.  The failing SELECT was a big clue that there was something wrong in the construction of the SQL.

Comment: It seems that Qt is not relevant to the issue because you don't use Qt SQL classes.

Answer (score 0):

There were leading spaces on user and study. Had been staring at the same debugger statements for too long and glossed over the extra spaces. The failing SELECT was a big clue that there was something wrong in the construction of the SQL.